# Reset unique_ptr<int[]> to existing int array of different size

Tags: c++, arrays, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have this code:

```
auto p = make_unique<int[]>(5);
auto tmp = new int[10];
// Some other code.
p = tmp;    <--- Does not work.
```

I have a unique_ptr `p`. I want to reassign the pointed array to another existing array (`tmp`). I would have expected the assignment to `delete[]` the old array and set it to `tmp`.

How can I achieve this result? Using `p.reset(tmp)` works, but how does `p` know about the new size?

Comment: [reset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) ?

Comment: I had a feeling this would be an easy one... I have edited the question slightly to make it more worthy.

Comment: The same way any pointer knows about size: It doesn't. Pointers just point. They have no idea how much stuff they point at or even if that stuff is still valid.

Comment: Then `p` would be a broken `unique_ptr<int[]>` in my example? At the end of the scope, it would not be able to `delete[]` the array correctly if it does not know about its size.

Comment: The magic sitting behind `new[]` on the other hand... it keeps some hidden book-keeping information so that it will know what to do when the object is given back with `delete`. What and where this book keeping is is not specified by the C++ Standard, but typically some extra storage is secretly requested and the book-keeping is stashed in the extra space. Say you ask for 10 `int`s. The stuff hiding under `new` asks for `10*sizeof(int) +sizeof(bookkeeping)`, fills out `bookkeeping`, and then returns a pointer to the 10 `int`s.

Comment: When `delete` is used, it looks at the book-keeping and, assuming your code didn't write out of bounds and squash it, follows the instructions to clean up.

Comment: Ok, so `delete[] tmp;` would delete all 10 elements (even though `tmp` is just a `int*`)? Likewise, the unique_ptr would be able to delete all 10 elements correctly?

Comment: That's a roger, rubber duckie.

Comment: Geeze. The things we have to do to get around the minimum comment size.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Why don't you just use std::vector?